# django models distinct is still returning duplicates

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

Im stumped ... and its probably obvious but i cannot seem to get distinct to remove the duplicates here

```
q = SubscriberPhoneNumber.objects.values_list('phone_number',flat=True).order_by('phone_number').distinct('phone_number')
print(q)
<QuerySet ['9711231234', '5095551212', '9994441212', '9994441212', '9711231234']>
```

as you can see 9711231234 appears twice (as does 9994441212)   (note these are not real phone numbers...)

here is the model

```
class SubscriberPhoneNumber(models.Model):
    subscriber = models.ForeignKey(SystemStatusSubscriber, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phone_number = EncryptedCharField(max_length=24, **null)
    country_code = models.CharField(max_length=8, default='+1')
```

I feel like im losing my mind ... and dont understand why `distinct` is not eliminating the duplicates   (I really want distinct on `country_code` and `phone_number` but just included `phone_number` to simplify the problem)  (I also do not need values_list but thought that might help select only the columns i am interested in)

(note that i can certainly cast the result to `set` to get unique values... but i feel like distinct is the right way to approach this, and cannot figure out how to make it work... )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `phone_number` field is an `EncryptedCharField`, I assume you use this package: [django-cryptographic-fields](https://github.com/foundertherapy/django-cryptographic-fields). As it states in it's repositories readme file:

> Due to the nature of the encrypted data, filtering by values contained
> in encrypted fields won't work properly. Sorting is also not
> supported.

This is the reason your distinct or even the ordering doesn't work (`['9711231234', '5095551212', '9994441212', '9994441212', '9711231234']` is not ordered). In general encrypting something and expecting to make such filters, etc. on them doesn't make much sense, if you really want to do this kinds of thing switch to a normal `CharField`.

Comment: derp :) thanks ... i figured it was obvious ... I was just missing that :) thanks a tonne :)